# Calling function pointer with a std::wostream parameter doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, function-pointers, iostream

I have a class that simplifies printing to the terminal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Functions to append line break(s):
wstring ln(wostream s) { s << endl; return L"\r\n"; }
wstring ln2(wostream s) { s << endl << endl; return L"\r\n\r\n"; }

class Log {
 private:
    wstring prefix, last_log;
 public:
    void operator=(wstring w) {
        system("cls"); // clear terminal
        wcout << prefix << w;
        last_log = w;
    }
    void operator+=(wstring w) {
        system("cls"); // clear terminal
        wcout << prefix << last_log << w;
        last_log += w;
    }

    void operator+=(wstring func(wostream s)) {
        last_log += func(wcout);
        //               ^^^^^
        // Visual Studio reports a syntax error here:
        // "Function ..." can not be referenced (is a deleted function)
    }

    void set_prefix(wstring w) {
        prefix = w;
        system("cls");
        wcout << prefix << last_log;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    Log log;
    log = L"Hello";
    log += L" World";
    log += ln; // Append line break!
}
```

In line 23, Visual Studio 2015 says: *(German)*

> Auf "Funktion "`std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &)` [mit _Elem=wchar_t, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (deklariert in Zeile 84 von "***[...]***\VC\include\ostream")" kann nicht verwiesen werden (ist eine gelöschte Funktion).

Translated:

> "Function "`std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &)` [mit _Elem=wchar_t, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared in line 84 of "***[...]***\VC\include\ostream")" can't be referenced (is a deleted function).

What is causing this error and how I can solve it?

Comment: Maybe try [tossing those streams around by reference instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432952/why-is-my-fstream-being-implicitly-deleted) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig It worked, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Please add the answer in the answer section and not as an edit to the post, I have rolled back but you can find your answer in this [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45068370/4)

Comment: @Aloso Some objects are simply not copyable. Input and output stream derivations fall into that category. Your passing `wcout` to a function expecting a stream interface by *value*, which introduces a copy-construction, and thus not allowed. The compiler is telling you the code you're trying to use would invoke a function (in this case the copy-ctor) that is *deleted*, and thus not available. If you ever wondered why input and output streams seem to be consistently hurled about in C++ by reference, now you know.